# How to display images from model in Django?

Tags: django

How to display images from model in templates?

I will display images from photos directory (upload_to='photos') in my template index.html. How to do?

For example:

My models

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', verbose_name='My Photo')
```

My views

```
def index(request):
    img = Photo.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"img": img})
```

My urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/?$', 'album.views.index'),
    (r'^static/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':           
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')}),
)
```

My template, index.html

```
{% for n in img %}
    ??
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything you need is well documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField). Youll need to pass your img into the template and use its url() method.

In your template you can do something like this:

```
{% for n in img %}
<img src="{{ n.nazwa.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it is well documented there, it is not clear to beginners how to do so. Currently I get the correct url, but no image

Answer (score 5):

You are missing in your root/project urls.py the following code.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Your code server will return module not found errors also until you import in the urls.py also. And for some reason, it has to be the root urls.py, even if you have individual urls.py files for separate applications

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

Comment: this helped me a lot! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

in the product case it becomes difficult to find the fault. this reduces it a bit

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
else:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```